# Select the Html.DropdownFor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
   <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        Brand
                                    </span>
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BrandMod.Id, c,"- Select Brand - ", new { @class = "form-control" ,id="brandid" })

                                </div>
```

"This is My Code for Drop Down and I want to select the selected item. I am trying this"

```
$("#brandid").change(function (rupp) {

    var a = $(this).select("option:selected").val();

});
```

"I am Unable to Load the Selected item."

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `$(this).val()` ?

Comment: Yes this is Working. Thank you for Your Support.

Comment: $("#brandid").change(function (rupp) {

            var a = $(this).val();//select("option:selected").val();
            alert(a);
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "~/Product/GetCategory" + a,
                    type="get"
                }
            ).done(function(rab)
            {
                alert(rab);

                });
            
        });

Comment: Now I am Unable to Make AJAX Call in same code.

Comment: Well, the code in this question doesn't attempt to make any AJAX calls.  So that seems like it could be the issue.  If you have a different issue with different code, best to create a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do what you're thinking:

```
$(this).select("option:selected").val()
```

In fact, it's *probably* either silently failing entirely or producing an error.  But no matter.  What you're trying to do is get the value from `this` (which is a `<select>` in your case).  That can be done simply with:

```
$(this).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Specification for getting value in jquery. You have already change event for this

```
$("#brandid").change(function (rupp) {

    var a =  $(this).val();

});
```

or

```
var a = $("#brandid").val();
```

Comment: Hy,
I am sorry as I am new in Programming and learning C#. I have 1 new Problem. I am creating Form from 2 Partial Views, the Element from 2nd Partial View is unable to go in Object